# I can't install any IMAP client for Node.js they all have 3 vulnerabilities

Tags: node.js, imap

```
# npm audit report

semver  <5.7.2
Severity: moderate
semver vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install imap@0.8.17, which is a breaking change
node_modules/semver
  utf7  >=1.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
  node_modules/utf7
    imap  >=0.8.18
    Depends on vulnerable versions of utf7
    node_modules/imap

3 moderate severity vulnerabilities
```

I tried to run `npm audit fix --force` and it doesn't find a version that works.